# Distributions (Generalized Functions)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Why is a distribution defined in terms of the inequality

$$ |\langle\Gamma, \psi\rangle| \leq C \sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup_{x \in S} | \partial^\alpha \psi |$$ for all $\psi \in C^\infty_c (\Omega)$, $S \subset \Omega$, $S$ compact, $K$ some constant, $\alpha$ a multi-index. And the existence of such constants $C$, $N$.

Now why is this definition written the way it is? Does it imply something about continuity of the distribution $\Gamma$ with respect to $\psi$? If so, what?

Obviously something like $$\Gamma (\psi) = \int_{\Omega} |f \psi| \, \,  d \mu(x) $$ satisfies this if we let $$K = \mu(S)\int_{\Omega} |f| \, \, d \mu(x)$$ so I see why this definition is satisfied. But why is it *necessary*?

Comment: It is not necessary, but it has proven to be very useful. And your guess is correct, it is for the continuity of $\Gamma$ with respect to $\psi$. For something like $\int \psi_n f \to \int\psi f$ you also need special convergence properties of $\psi_n\to\psi$, namely the uniform convergence. This uniform convergence is not necessary, but has proven to be very useful.
BTW, you should have a look at your definition and the dependencies of your $S$ and $N$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this properly, one has to talk about the **reason** for introducing distributions first.

One of the main reasons for this is to be able to define a sort of generalized derivative for objects which are to "singular" to possess derivatives in a classical sense. For example, the functions

$$
f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
0, & x<0,\\
1, & x\geq0
\end{cases}
$$

has no derivative (at $0$) in the classical sense, but we will see below that it has one in the sense of distributions.

First, let us note (in dimension $1$ for simplicity), that if $f \in C^1(\Bbb{R})$ and $g \in C_c^\infty (\Bbb{R})$ (we could take any interval), then partial integration yields

$$
\int_\Bbb{R} f'(x) g(x) \, dx = f(b) g(b) - f(a) g(a) - \int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx = -\int_\Bbb{R} f(x) g'(x) \, dx,
$$

where $a < b$ are chosen such that ${\rm supp}(g) \subset (a,b)$.

The first idea is now to **identify** the function $f$ with the functional

$$
\varphi_f : C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{K}, g \mapsto \int_\Bbb{R} f(x) g(x) \,dx,
$$

where $\Bbb{K} \in \{\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{C}\}$ is your favorite field. To do this, one should observe (this is sometimes called the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations) that if $\varphi_f (g) = 0$ holds for all $g$ and a (continuous/locally integrable) function $f$, then $f \equiv 0$ (a.e.).

As the calculation above shows, we have $\varphi_{f'}(g) = - \varphi_f (g')$ for all $g$.

We note that the right hand side (that is, the map $g \mapsto \Phi (g')$ makes sense as soon as $\Phi$ is a linear functional on $C_c^\infty$ (for example $\Phi = \varphi_f$), so that we **could define** the "generalized derivative" of such a functional $\Phi$ by **defining**

$$\Phi' : C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{K}, g \mapsto - \Phi(g')$$

Observe that this is well-defined because of $g' \in C_c^\infty$ if $g \in C_c^\infty$.

The new idea now is to define a new class of **generalized functions** as the set of all (reasonable) linear functionals on $C_c^\infty$. As seen above, we will then be able to define a generalized derivative of these generalized functions such that it **generalizes** the ordinary derivative (i.e. $\varphi_f ' = \varphi_{f'}$ if $f \in C^1$).

But all we **really** wanted to do is to be able to define arbitrary derivatives of continuous/locally integrable functions. So it would really suffice to consider the class of all (generalized) derivatives (or arbitrary order) of generalized functions from the set $\{\varphi_f \mid f \in C^0(\Bbb{R}) \}$ (or replace $C^0$ by $L^1_{\rm loc}$). Instead of these "nice" objects, the class of **all** linear functionals on $C_c^\infty$ (in contrast to the continuous ones) would contain many pathological functionals which we want to avoid.

Instead of introducing this definition, we observe that each of the functionals $\varphi_f$ is **continuous** in the sense described in your question (as you observed yourself). We also observe that this continuity property is inherited by the generalized derivative, i.e. if $\Phi$ is continuous in the sense described above, then $\Phi ' $ is also a continuous linear functional in this sense (**why**?).

One can even show (this is done in Rudin's "Functional Analysis") that this definition yields the (more or less) **smallest** class of "generalized" functions such that it contains all continuous functions and arbitrary derivatives of those. More precisely, for each compact set $K \subset \Omega$ and each distribution $\Phi$, there is some $N \in \Bbb{N}$ and continuous functions $f_\alpha$ such that

$$
\Phi(f) = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq N}\int_\Omega f_\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x) \, dx
$$

holds for all $g \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with support in $K$.

This observation justifies the choice of functionals made above.

---

Also note that there is a general principle at work here: We want to have a "big" space of generalized functions. To achieve this, we choose a very "small" space ($C_c^\infty(\Omega)$) with a very strong topology/notion of convergence, i.e.

$$
f_n \to f \text{ in the sense of } C_c^\infty (\Omega)
$$

if and only if there is a compact set $K \subset \Omega$ such that ${\rm supp}(f_n) \subset K$ for all $n$ and $\partial^\alpha f_n \to \partial^\alpha f$ uniformly for all $\alpha$ and define our "large" space to be the **dual space** of the "small" space, i.e. the set of all continuous linear functionals.

Comment: Would it be equivalent to say that $f_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{D}$ if and only if $\partial^\alpha f_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{D}$? My professor asserted the topology as such, and used it to prove the continuity of distributions, by noting that if $\{ \psi_n \} \subset \mathscr{D}$ goes to $0$, then the distribution is continuous if and only if it also goes to $0$.

Comment: Yes, the definition easily shows that $f_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{D}$ iff $\partial^\alpha f_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{D}$ **for all $\alpha$**. Here "$\Leftarrow$" follows using $\alpha = 0$. One can also show (using only the definitions) that a functional $\Phi$ on $C_c^\infty$ is a distribution (i.e. coninuous) if and only if $\Phi(f_n) \to 0$ as soon as $f_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{D}$.
$$
\qquad
$$
Note that $f_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{D}$ is equivalent to ${\rm supp}(f_n) \subset K$ for some fixed compact $K \subset \Omega$ together with $\partial^\alpha f_n \to 0$ **uniformly** for all $\alpha$.